# How to run Continuity Activation Tool from Recovery HD's command line?

Tags: terminal, continuity, macos, recovery-hd

I use [Continuity Activation Tool](https://github.com/dokterdok/Continuity-Activation-Tool/) to enable Continuity on my early-2011 13" MBP with an upgraded AirPort card. However, El Capitan's Rootless feature has forced me to use a modded version of CAT that can disable Rootless, which worked almost perfectly in the early betas. However, later betas implemented a different method of disabling Rootless that can only be done from the Recovery HD Terminal. I've counted, and going back and forth between Recovery HD and my startup disk to use CAT requires a total of at least 5 reboots, which isn't fun on a 4-year-old HDD.

My question: Is it possible to use CAT in Recovery HD's command line? If my math is right, that should limit the number of reboots to a relatively tolerable 3.